# I want to convert these outputs to a list

Tags: python, numbers, primes

I am a Python beginner.

I got a prime number within the specified range. However, I couldn't convert it to a list.

I also tried converting it to a string and back to a list.

```
import random

lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))  
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))  

for num in range(lower,upper + 1):  
   if num > 1:  
       for i in range(2, num):  
           if (num % i) == 0:  
               break  
       else:
         print(num)
```

Comment: what is the expected input/output?

Comment: What dou you mean by "convert to a list"? If you want to create a one-element list containing only `num`, then `[ num ]` is the right syntax…

Comment: You're thinking about this wrong - you can't expect to "convert" the data to a list because there is nothing to convert. You need to *collect* the results into a list, as you comput them.

Comment: input, output is prime number's range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an empty list, and every time you find a prime number, append it to the list. Then you can print the list at the end:

```
nums = []
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):  
   if num > 1:  
       for i in range(2, num):  
           if (num % i) == 0:  
               break  
       else:
           nums.append(num)

print(nums)
```

Note that you only need to iterate up the square root of `num`, any factor beyond that can only have another factor which is less than it:

```
from math import sqrt

nums = []
for num in range(lower,upper + 1):  
   if num > 1:  
       for i in range(2, int(sqrt(num))):  
           if (num % i) == 0:  
               break  
       else:
           nums.append(num)

print(nums)
```